# How to add bottom round icon like gmail application android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

[image]

i want to make view like this with a button at the bottom. how can i do it? i am new to material design. I tried RecyclerView but i don't know whats that button.

Comment: relative layout and imageview can do the job more or less keep

Answer (score 2):

you have to use FloatingActionButton try this.

http://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/
this library can help you. 
When you add library to your project write your xml file like that:

`<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewID"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>`

Comment: If you want to animation, yes. I suggested it just for rounded image view.